# Stitching of video frames from two calibrated CCTV cameras

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I have two CCTV cameras setup in a room with sufficient overlapping region. The stream from these cameras is calibrated. I used OpenCV stitching python code from [here](https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching) to stitch two respective frames of videos from two cameras. The stitching output has shaky movements in it. How to overcome these movements? Please suggest.

Comment: how far apart are the cameras? do you want to stitch the floor only? -- if your output "shakes", you apparently recalculate the stitching for every pair of frames. wrong. do that once, then save it, and apply it.

Comment: Distance between cameras is 2ft. No, I don't want to stitch the floor. I am doing stitching for every pair of frames. Will you please elaborate on recalculation? What to recalculate and apply?

Comment: generally, for views that do *not* share an optical center, you can't stitch them. the model for that is a sphere, or two spheres. -- *translated/shifted* views of a flat surface can be stitched because the model is a flat plane. -- just show us some pictures and explain what you're trying to accomplish with all of that. you can't just decide on an approach if you don't know that it's even applicable.

Comment: Please check the calibrated images from two cameras, for [left_image](https://ibb.co/8667Rcg) and [right_image](https://ibb.co/q56916y). I want to stitch such two frames from ceiling mounted cameras which are looking to floor and the objects coming across.

Comment: if you can, mount the cameras next to each other so their views cross right in front of their lenses. then you have a chance of getting a reasonable stitch. if not, you will get noticeable artefacts. that is unavoidable. -- or get ceiling-mounted panoramic cameras. they give a 360 degree half-sphere view "naturally"

Comment: Please check the camera positions [camera_position](https://ibb.co/bFG0s7m).

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching/discussions/148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaky movements from stitching image streams from cameras were already reported [here](https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching/discussions/148). The stitching pipeline will calibrate its internal cameras independently on each `stitch`. In case of video stitching, the issue is that this results in some warping from one frame to the other. The solution is to calibrate the cameras only with the first frame and then afterwards only use those cameras. This will also save the time needed for feature matching for each frame. To do this, you could inherit a `VideoStitcher` from `Stitcher` where you overwrite `initialize_stitcher()` and `stitch()`

```
from stitching import Stitcher
from stitching.images import Images

class VideoStitcher(Stitcher):

    def initialize_stitcher(self, **kwargs):
        super().initialize_stitcher(kwargs)
        self.cameras = None
        self.cameras_registered = False
        
    def stitch(self, images, feature_masks=[]):
        self.images = Images.of(
            images, self.medium_megapix, self.low_megapix, self.final_megapix
        )

        if not self.cameras_registered:
            imgs = self.resize_medium_resolution()
            features = self.find_features(imgs, feature_masks)
            matches = self.match_features(features)
            imgs, features, matches = self.subset(imgs, features, matches)
            cameras = self.estimate_camera_parameters(features, matches)
            cameras = self.refine_camera_parameters(features, matches, cameras)
            cameras = self.perform_wave_correction(cameras)
            self.estimate_scale(cameras)
            self.cameras = cameras
            self.cameras_registered = True

        imgs = self.resize_low_resolution()
        imgs, masks, corners, sizes = self.warp_low_resolution(imgs, self.cameras)
        self.prepare_cropper(imgs, masks, corners, sizes)
        imgs, masks, corners, sizes = self.crop_low_resolution(
            imgs, masks, corners, sizes
        )
        self.estimate_exposure_errors(corners, imgs, masks)
        seam_masks = self.find_seam_masks(imgs, corners, masks)

        imgs = self.resize_final_resolution()
        imgs, masks, corners, sizes = self.warp_final_resolution(imgs, self.cameras)
        imgs, masks, corners, sizes = self.crop_final_resolution(
            imgs, masks, corners, sizes
        )
        self.set_masks(masks)
        imgs = self.compensate_exposure_errors(corners, imgs)
        seam_masks = self.resize_seam_masks(seam_masks)

        self.initialize_composition(corners, sizes)
        self.blend_images(imgs, seam_masks, corners)
        return self.create_final_panorama()
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you for your valuable suggestion and code block. It worked very well and removes the shakiness in the stitched video. In the stitched output for some frames I am experiencing the disappearance of person and cluttering of objects. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: Hi @LukasWeber, do you have any idea how to avoid the disappearance of person in the stitching result? Please check the stitched frame [disappearance_stitching](https://ibb.co/VJYhH07)

Comment: Thats a hard problem. You would 1. need to detect areas which should be preserved (Person) and then 2. tell the stitching algorithm that it shouldnt cut through this area. https://www.ecva.net/papers/eccv_2018/papers_ECCV/papers/Charles_Herrmann_Object-centered_image_stitching_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf as reference

Comment: Thank you @LukasWeber. I will check the research paper.

Comment: @Learner I posted a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723819/can-i-specify-areas-which-should-be-preserved-during-opencv-image-stitching)

Comment: Thanks @LukasWeber. The question is quite clear and defines problem well.

Comment: @Learner feel free to upvote to give it more attention

Comment: Hi @LukasWeber, Using the VideoStitcher class above, we tried to fix the homography for each camera. What about the adjacent homographies between pair of cameras? Does the code incorporate adjacent homographies?