# Can I specify areas which should be preserved during OpenCV image stitching?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching, seam-carving

Fig. 1 of [Object-centered image stitching](https://www.ecva.net/papers/eccv_2018/papers_ECCV/papers/Charles_Herrmann_Object-centered_image_stitching_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf) shows an typical issue when working with image stitching: a specific part of an image should be preserved but the seam cuts right through it.

I know that seam carving (e.g. [here](https://github.com/vivianhylee/seam-carving) and [here](https://github.com/andrewdcampbell/seam-carving)) use energy maps to calculate a path where it's "cheap" to cut through. To mark areas which should be preserved, we could penalize cutting though there by increasing the energy in this area.

To me it seams like OpenCVs [GraphCutSeamFinder](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/db/dda/classcv_1_1detail_1_1GraphCutSeamFinder.html#a35191986128771a43662f02a25b0174a) provides something in this direction: `bad_region_penalty`

However, the [find function](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/db/dda/classcv_1_1detail_1_1GraphCutSeamFinder.html#aea2fc0865be1d3134b8dde43ae3e9dd4) does not seem to allow making use of something which might penalize a bad region. The masks which are passed in in [stitching_detailed](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py#L438) are only updating the warped masks.

Can I specify areas which should be preserved during OpenCV image stitching using  GraphCutSeamFinder or other seam finders? Or does the `bad_region_penalty` parameter exists for a complete other use case? The seam finders are implemented [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/stitching/src/seam_finders.cpp) but I'm not familiar with C++